# Remove www.* in NuxtLink's

Tags: nuxt.js

I have deployed a Nuxt app via Vercel. But it seems `<NuxtLink to="/about">` wants to add a `https://www.example.com/about` which is causing redirects to the `https://example.com/about`. Is there a way to set a base url of sorts to make it not go to www. and instead the naked domain?

Comment: This is more of a registrar config to have only the apex set there, if you inspect the generated link in your DOM, it is probably not having any `www` in it. So, not a Nuxt issue.

Comment: Yeah, Vercel was for some reason redirecting it to www. instead of the naked domain. Thanks for flagging.